# Python: Create a duplicate of an array

Tags: python, list, pointers, arrays

I have an double array

```
alist[1][1]=-1
alist2=[]
for x in xrange(10):
    alist2.append(alist[x])
alist2[1][1]=15

print alist[1][1]
```

and I get 15.  Clearly I'm passing a pointer rather than an actual variable... Is there an easy way to make a **seperate** double array (no shared pointers) **without having to do a double for loop**?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list of lists is not usually a great solution for making a 2d array. You probably want to use numpy, which provides a very useful, efficient n-dimensional array type. numpy arrays can be copied.

Other solutions that are usually better than a plain list of lists include a dict with tuples as keys (`d[1, 1]` would be the 1, 1 component) or defining your own 2d array class. Of course, dicts can be copied and you could abstract copying away for your class.

To copy a list of lists, you can use `copy.deepcopy`, which will go one level deep when copying.

Answer (score 9):

I think [copy.deepcopy()](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) is for just this case.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `somelist[:]`, that is a slice like `somelist[1:2]` from beginning to end, to create a (shallow) copy of a list. Applying this to your for-loop gives:

```
alist2 = []
for x in xrange(10):
   alist2.append(alist[x][:])
```

This can also be written as a list comprehension:

```
alist2 = [item[:] for item in alist]
```

Answer (score 1):

make a copy of the list when append.

```
  alist2.append(alist[x][:])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're already looping over the list anyway then just copying the inner lists as you go is easiest, as per **seanmonstar**'s answer.

If you just want to do a deep copy of the list you could call `copy.deepcopy()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can do something like:

```
new_list = old_list[:]
```

So you could perhaps throw that in your singular for loop?

```
for x in range(10):
    alist2.append(alist[x][:])
```